# Encoding of a Project Java + hudson

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, hudson

I'm have a problem with an server Hudson.

My project java, my workspace and all class have a encoding UTF-8, but when trying to generate a build happens a error with encoding.

I use Ubuntu server 11.04, and to development Ubuntu 11.10.

the error what happening  is:

```
/home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/SCUV/workspace/scuv.persistence/src/main/java/br/com/digitaldoc/scuv/abstracts/Bean.java:[29,18] error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII
```

in this line have "ã"

Anyone know how to solve this problem?

This is output of console:

```
Started by timer
Updating http://192.168.3.100/svn/SCUV/trunk revision: Apr 23, 2012 8:05:42 AM depth:infinity ignoreExternals: false
At revision 40
no change for http://192.168.3.100/svn/SCUV/trunk since the previous build
[workspace] $ mvn clean compile test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Reactor build order: 
[INFO]   SCUV
[INFO]   SCUV Persistence Module
[INFO]   SCUV WebService Module
[INFO]   SCUV WebApp Module
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SCUV
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, compile, test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] No goals needed for project - skipping
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building SCUV Persistence Module
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, compile, test]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting file set: /home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/SCUV/workspace/scuv.persistence/target (included: [**], excluded: [])
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/SCUV/workspace/scuv.persistence/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

/home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/SCUV/workspace/scuv.persistence/src/main/java/br/com/digitaldoc/scuv/inject/ScuvPersistenceAPI.java:[14,33] error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII

/home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/SCUV/workspace/scuv.persistence/src/main/java/br/com/digitaldoc/scuv/inject/ScuvPersistenceAPI.java:[14,34] error: unmappable character for encoding ASCII

////has more classes with the same error

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 23 08:05:54 BRT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Recording test results
Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 40% sets the build as unstable
Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 60% sets the build as failure
Performance: Recording JUnit reports '**/TEST*.xml'
Sending e-mails to: asdasd@asdad.com
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: SCUV #7 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What is your build system? Maven? Ant? (`src/main/java` suggests Maven) Whatever you use, you probably need to tell the compiler which encoding to use. How to do that depends on what you use for building your project.

Comment: Maven 2.2.1. if I build the project from the command line, works. just does not work by clicking the maven build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the `~/.hudson` folder and configure it again.

Tell me if it works.

Comment: when I use the parameter in the call of the war hudson: -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 works :D